# Solve differential equation using Laplace transform with weird condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$y'' + 2y' + y = 0$$

Where $y(0) = 0$ and $y(1)=2$.

I first try to apply Laplace transform in both sides which I get:

$$s^2 Y(s) - sy(0) - y'(0) + 2(sY(s)-y(0)) + Y(s) = 0$$

After this I substitute the $y(0)=0$ so I get:

$$Y(s) = y'(0)/(s^2+2s+1)$$

But now I am stuck. What should I do now?

Thank you in advance. And sorry I do not know how to write in LaTex.

Comment: Writing in mathjax is not hard. I will edit this for you for this post

Comment: Yes I am sure that the second condition is y(1)=2

Comment: All that was necessary was to append dollar signs `$` and `$$` to your post. Also, just leave two blank lines - using HTML tags like <br> is ... strange to me

Comment: $y'(0)$ is still a constant, call it $D$ if you like. Simply inverse Laplace transform what you have right now and plug in the second boundary condition afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by linearity,
$$y(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{y'(0)}{s^2+2s+1}\right)=y'(0)\,\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}\right)=y'(0)te^{-t}.$$
Now find the constant $y'(0)$ by imposing $y(1)=2$.